# How to read textfile line by line into textarea in codename one

Tags: codenameone

pls, I want to read a textfile line by line into textarea in codename one. I placed my textfile in src directory because i want to pack it with my apk.  I used this code InputStream url = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(this.getClass(), "/b1.txt" ); I was able to get all the text in the file once. I want to pick the text line by line instead of once into different textarea. pls help me out with the code. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can parse it after reading the stream. Convert the Stream into a String and tokenize it with the carriage return char.

Answer (score 2):

As Tim said in the comment the easiest thing to do is something like:

```
InputStream is = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(this.getClass(), "/b1.txt" );
String s = Util.readToString(is, "UTF-8");
for(String line : StringUtil.tokenize(s, '\n')) {
     // line represents each line in the file...
}
```